# Mongoose/MongoDB - Reference another Schema without ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have two schemas.

```
var carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    make: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    model: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    year: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: config.MIN_YEAR,
        max: config.MAX_YEAR
    },
    color: {
        type: String
    },
    price: [
        // don't know what to put here...
    ],
 });


var priceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    car_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    amount: {
       type: Number,
       min: 0
    },
    year: {
       type: Number,
       min: config.MIN_YEAR,
       max: config.MAX_YEAR
    }
 });
```

As you can see from the two schemas above, I'm trying to make a reference to the price schema from the car schema. I know that you can do it by referencing the ObjectId (`_id`), but I need to reference the price schema through the `car_id`. The reason is because I'm reading all the data from a CSV file which already defined the table headers. Is there any possible way in mongoose to make this reference?

Comment: Why not keep both `car_id` and `_id`(newly created)? Because with other ids you won't be able to benefit from `populate` for one.

Comment: @TalhaAwan how would I structure my schemas in a way that would allow me to utilize both `car_id` and `_id` to be able to make the reference to price schema? that's what I'm not quite getting

Comment: When you import a record from CSV file and create a price object out it you'll have both `car_id` and `_id` (which mongoose enters by default). Enter the `_id` in the array of price references in car.

Comment: @TalhaAwan `price: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Price"
        }
    ]` is what I originally wrote (which is what I think you were telling me to do), but I didn't see how this would allow me to reference all the prices where `id` == `car_id`

Comment: I think you're mixing up the relationship between car and price. What I assume is that from CSV, you have a car with multiple prices over the years? If that's the case, you can embed the prices in the car itself (don't need price collection in my opinion).

Comment: If you do need a separate collection, you can either keep array of price references in car or keep car reference in each price document. Either way the references should be mongo id. The `car_id` from the CSV you can store as is in car document but you may not want to use it for referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Define price schema on top of car schema and then put price schema to your car schema.

```
...
color: {
    type: String
},
price: [priceSchema]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var priceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    car_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    amount: {
       type: Number,
       min: 0
    },
    year: {
       type: Number,
       min: config.MIN_YEAR,
       max: config.MAX_YEAR
    }
 });
```

Then make the model for Price as

```
var Price = mongoose.model('Price', priceSchema);
```

Followed by:

```
var carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    make: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    model: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    year: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: config.MIN_YEAR,
        max: config.MAX_YEAR
    },
    color: {
        type: String
    },
    price: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Price'
    },
 });
```

Then make the car model as:

```
var Car = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);
```

This will do the trick. You can then run your queries as:

```
Car.find({_id: 1})
.populate('price')
.exec(function(err, car) {
    // do stuff with your car objects
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const thesisReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    thesisID: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Thesis",
      require: true,
    },
    studentID: {
      type: String,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    reviewDate: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      require: true,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } } //make sure you add this otherwise it wont work!
);

thesisReviewSchema.virtual("student" //have to use this name to populate , { 
  ref: "User", // we are referring user model
  localField: "studentID", //studentID is the local filed 
  foreignField: "userID", //it is the filed from user table 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("ThesisReview", thesisReviewSchema);
```

For ref: **https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals**

Comment: I think this answer could be improved with a small example. This way if the linked documentation ever rots, the answer is still complete.